# How could an organism move through space freely without the use of technology?

Tags: science-based, science-fiction, aliens

The organism is human-like in that it is intelligent, sentient, and has a humanoid figure. On its planet, the species has access to a massive source of organic energy unlike anything on Earth. Essentially what I am asking is, could this organism "teleport" as if it is constantly jumping through wormholes naturally, without the use of technology?

Rules can be bent a little. If I forgot to specify anything important, ask.

Comment: The starseeds from Larry Niven's _Known Space_ universe, which the Outsiders follow, aren't humanoid  and probably aren't sentient, but they were the first thingsI thought of.

Comment: First thing first, it seems that in your world some kinds of wormholes works with technology, right? Which kind is it? And how an energy source on the planet affects someone jumping around the outer space? It doesn't look like this information is in any way relevant. Please clarify.

Comment: Could this being be a 4th or 5th dimensional being? They could most likely (at least, you could fudge the truth and say that) walk in directions that do not exist in the 3 dimensional plane, ones beyond the main 6 we know (up down left right forward back). Walking in those directions could seem like teleportation to us, but by sheer fact they could do that, they could do a lot more which might be undesirable in this case.

Comment: I don't see why not. Consider Alfred Bester's [The Stars My Destination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Stars_My_Destination). Through evolution, *jaunting* (personal teleportation) had developed, but IIRC it was basically a sight-to-sight ability. The hero becomes the first to jaunt through space, traveling 100s of thousands of miles. This novel predates the concept of wormholes and such, but those factors would likely contribute to such an ability.

Comment: If you can teleport, why go anywhere but the destination? Space is inhospitable, hanging out there without a spacesuit isn't a survival trait.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind warping the nature of space a little, that source of organic energy is truly gargantuan and you're happy to hand wave away... erm... pretty much everything, then sure!

Lets start with some assumptions:

E=mc<sup>2</sup>

We're fans of the Gauss-Bonnet gravity metric (or similar ways of describing the nature of spacetime where exotic matter isn't needed to form a wormhole or major spatial distortion).

Your energy source is nigh-on infinite.

Your creatures have unparalleled control of this energy source (like, they can manipulate it in an extra couple of dimensions that we can't even perceive levels of control) and are pulling it from 'elsewhere', so they aren't constantly storing it within themselves.

Your creatures are really, *really* tough.

---

OK. Now we're all set up for 2 things: Gravity surfing and wormhole manufacture.

1: The creatures summon a shedload of this energy and dump it (contained somehow using their brand of space magic) in front of themselves (or even at the front of their bodies). Due to my first assumption this is the same as dropping matter in front of yourself, which will pull the matter of your body forwards. Side effects include insane tidal effects (so you and anyone nearby need to be ridiculously tough) and violation of the conservation of momentum, but that's OK, you can hand wave that the momentum is transferred to whatever mystical plane you're drawing power from.

2: By manipulating the same energy (remember, it's mass) in an extra couple of spatial dimensions it's possible to cause spacetime to bend in on itself (as long as space actually works that way, which as of yet we can't really confirm. *Waves hands*). If your guys can do the same thing in the right way in multiple locations in our paltry set of three spatial dimensions then it's possible they can tear a stable, traversable wormhole through which they can then pop themselves. Side effects include.. erm.. tearing a hole in the fabric of the universe.

Go space aliens!!

Answer (score 2):

It's sortof unclear what you mean. I'm going to assume you want: *"Evolved method an alien uses to teleport unspecified distances without using supporting artificial technology."*

**Since this is [science-based](/questions/tagged/science-based), your answer is "no".  You can't do this.**

First, teleporting is hard:

- Teleportation (instantaneous) is not possible according to known laws of physics.
- Teleportation (via wormholes) is (maybe?) theoretically possible, but absurdly complex, comes with relativistic gotchas, and requires support structure outside the host organism.
- Teleportation (quantum information over classical substrate) requires the organism to destroy itself, and then be reassembled by support structures at source and destination.

So teleporting is only dubiously possible, and at that it requires (currently magitech) support structure outside of the object being teleported (to handle dissassembly, or propping open a wormhole mouth with negative energy, if such can actually be produced).

This means that it's *not inconceivable* that a highly advanced civilization could construct "stargate" type point-to-point devices using their extremely advanced technology developed using focused R&D backed by solid mathematics and physical theory.

Essentially what you're asking is for biology to replicate this. This is not something evolution can do.

Evolution works by gradual changes, and you get complex features (eyes, brains, etc.) by arranging them out of simpler components (light-sensitive cells, neurons, etc.).  Evolution works because partial successes confer a survival advantage.  The light-sensitive organelle in the single-celled *Euglena gracilis* isn't an eye by a longshot, but it's a lot better than nothing at all.

This doesn't apply here.  There's no partial success.  If you can get halfway to a teleporter, say by dissassembling yourself into energy ready for transmission, you don't have a survival advantage.  You've just turned yourself into exploding goo.  And you don't really have any way of creating the necessary support structure either.  You have to come up with some symbiotic relationship of biological co-evolution that produces teleportation of half of itself as an emergent side-effect.  Erm, no.

Comment: I'm new here, so this might be an ignorant comment. Why is [science-based] restricted to extrapolations of current science? In 1900 who would have believed that the smartphone was anything other than fantastical, a dream (presuming they could even dream it) that could never be real. The precept of your answer seems to be that teleportation involves motion. Maybe it doesn't, and we just don't know it yet.

Comment: @RichF How else could we base it, other than on current science? Current science is confirmed science thus something you can base things on.

Comment: @AngelPray I don't know. The description for the [science-based] tag confuses me. Apparently it is for questions somewhere between **hard-science** and **pseudo-science**, leaning towards the former, but not necessarily being actual reality.  Detractors of evolution have referred to it as pseudo-science for well over 100 years, and more recently the science of climate change is getting the same treatment. With the tag, I don't know where the lines are drawn.

Comment: I personally treat 'science based' as 'include science somehow, make it as serious as my question looks'. This has come into play in a couple of science based evolution questions, and in questions with a dubious term like 'massive source of organic energy' I tend to assume that it's wavering more to the pseudo-science tag and just wants to know if there's any way that a concept could be *linked* to any reasonable theory, rather than the hard science 'how can my concept arise from a well proven theory'. :D

Comment: @RichF Your point is well-taken. However, I do feel like I addressed the speculative aspects here (e.g. wormholes aren't current science, but I talk about what would be probably required to use them anyway). The correspondence principle places limits on what future tech or bio-pseudo-tech can likely do. The overall point of my answer is that I see no plausible  speculative-scientific way for teleportation to evolve without artificial technology.

Comment: imallett, Your answer was well thought-out, and I +1'd it. Still, parts of it are worth questioning. Consider "motion" itself. Close your eyes for 3 seconds, then open them.  Everything looks the same, right? But you've just moved over 55 miles, taking into account Earth's rotation on its axis and the revolving Earth around the Sun.  Not considered is the rotation of our galaxy nor the motion of the galaxy away (presumably) from where the Big Bang happened. Who can say what other motions are at play (maybe > 3D) and might some day be harnessable.

Comment: @RichF Your example is mainly an effect of relativity. "Everything looks the same, right?" Yes it does, since I don't move in my own reference frame. If you were on the Sun you might see me moving, but the point of relativity is that no reference frame is privileged.¶ By contrast, the idea of teleportation is to change your location in relation to your surroundings at the speed of light. Maybe this is possible in the future. But again, the point is that you can't _evolve_ it biologically (my best guess at interpreting question). It must be a revolutionary tech; not an evolutionary accident.